# Integração do Prestashop com ERP

Tags: web-service, integração, e-commerce, erp

Necessito que exista integração de pedidos, clientes, produtos e alteração de preços/promoções do Prestashop com ERP.

No caso o objetivo seria o seguinte:

1 - Ao fazer uma venda ou cadastrar/editar algum produto ou cliente na loja virtual exista a possibilidade de exportar para atualizar no ERP;

2 - Quando for realizada algum cadastro/alteração em produto ou cliente no ERP , haver a possibilidade de importar para atualizar o Prestashop.

Obs: Estou utilizando a versão 1.6 do Prestashop

Existe como fazer?

Comment: Encontrei a solução nestes dois manuais: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Webservice+Parameters http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation